# Font weight value is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have tried to give a `font-weight` property to text widgets but it's not working properly, which will show the same bolder appearance for the values 
`100,200,300,400 and 500` and show a big effect on `600`. What is this issue? How can I fix it?

```css
.flip-menu-text {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.125rem;
    padding: .5625rem 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<span class="flip-menu-text">Widgets</span>
```

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872486/font-weight900-only-working-in-firefox#comment11088683_8872514

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the CSS you provided and more to do with the font in question (which you did not specify).

Take [this font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans), for example. It has 400 (normal), 600, 700 (bold), 800, and 300 font weight styles.

As [stated by CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/):

> In order to see any effect using values other than 400 or 700, the font being used must have built-in faces that match those specified weights.

In short, if you are not happy with the `font-weight` available, try using a different font.

Comment: No, they don't have the same effect. Whatever font you're using simply doesn't have a font definition for the `500` font weight, so it defaults to the non-bold version.